# Polymorphic templated classes with polymorphic template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, idioms

In a simplistic design, a class B inherits a class A polymorphically. 
A templated class, `Base<T>` has a `T*` member that is used for further operations. A `Derived<T>` inherits from `Base<T>` polymorphically. 
What would be the syntax that allows this kind of object creation:

```
Base<A>* a = new Derived<B>();
```

For further reference, the code I used looks like this (of course, the conversion does not succeed):

```
class A
{
public:
  A()
  {
    cout<< " A  ";
  }
  virtual void one()
  {
    cout<<" 1 ";
  }

};

class B: public A
{
public:
  B()
  {
    cout << " B  ";
  }
  void one()

  {
      cout << " 2 ";
  }
};

template <class T>
class Base
{

public:
    T* thing;
  Base()
  {
    cout<<"Base";
    thing = new T;
  }
  template <class S>
  Base(Base<S>* obj)
  {
    thing = obj->thing;
  }
  virtual void poly(){ thing->one();}
};
template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:
  Derived()
  {
    cout << "DERIVED ";
  }
  virtual void poly(){ 
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //Base<A>* a = (new Derived<B>());
  return 0;
}
```

Virtual destructors and proper memory management omitted on purpose for code brevity.

*EDIT* : the sole purpose of this construction would be to keep, say, a list of `BaseTemplated<BasePolymorphic>*` pointers together, and not use `BaseTemplated<Derived1>` to `BaseTemplated<DerivedN>` for all N subclasses of a base, polymorphic class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, tell me when we get to the "simplistic" part.

Peel back all half of the  templates to just concentrate on the part you're trying to polymorph). Eventually you have distinct classes `Base<A>` and `Base<B>`. (the latter through derivation of `Derived<B>`).

Neither of these *inherit* from their respective template parameters. Therefore the relationship (hierarchical or otherwise) of `A` to `B` is irrelevant. `Base<A>` and `Base<B>` are distinct and unrelated, and therefore what you're trying to do as-writen cannot work. In fact, even if the *did* inherit from a `A` and `B` respectively, the very best you could hope for is an `A*` pointer, which you aren't using in your sample.

And I'll *gladly* delete this if shown otherwise, because I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Mathematically, this scheme should somehow make sense: `A<-B`, `Base<T> <- Derived<T>` and hence `Base<A> <- Derived<B>` (I don't really know how to call it, perhaps some sort of covariance related mechanism). That's what I was trying to achieve. Funny part is, I think I saw something like this somewhere and it worked, but I never took the time to read that code contraption. All in all, the simplistic part was just the "idea"  - I wanted to know whether this or something similar can be semantically valid in C++ (and if yes, how?).

Comment: @teodron To my knowledge it cannot be with the construct you have here. `Base<A>` and Base<B> are ultimately unrelated. That they each have a member variable that are part of their own polymorphic hierarchy is not relevant. The Base<T> expansions are still, none the less, unrelated. I hope that made sense in my description.

Comment: Thanks, Iĺl try to rethink the design.

Comment: Yes, what you are trying to achieve is a covariance relationship between the types. Since C++ templates are invariant, this can't work.

Answer (score 3):

A bag of apple `Base<B>` is not a bag of fruit `Base<A>` because you can put a peach, a cherry, and a pear in a bag of fruit.

Answer (score 1):

This can't work for pointers. The result of `new Derived<B>` cannot be assigned to `Base<A>*`, in fact it can't be even assigned to `Derived<A>*` since all those types are unrelated. Do you really need this relationship between the templated wrappers? Wouldn't it suffice to guarantee the convertibility of the values of `Base<B>` and `Base<A>` (as the standard smart pointers do)? You already have this with the templated conversion constructor...

```
//...
Base<B> tB(new B);
Base<A> tA = tB;
//...
```