# C++: Cannot convert argument 1 from Child non-template class to Parent template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, radix, derived

I know there is a lot of these "cannot convert argument" questions here, but I promise I looked around a lot and I think my particular case hasn't been asked yet, plus I have tried debugging this for quite a few hours but can't seem to get it.

Basically, I am creating a Component system for a 2D game engine. I have separated my logic into two parts: `Component` and `ComponentSystem`. The `Component` class will store only data, while the `ComponentSystem` will update and manipulate that data accordingly.

The `ComponentSystem` base class is abstract with a template to specify which `Component` the system will be using. Here is the .h file:

```
// =================================================================================================
// == COMPONENT SYSTEM CLASS =======================================================================
// =================================================================================================
template <class T>
class ComponentSystem
{
public:
    // -- ctor & dtor
    ComponentSystem<T>();
    ~ComponentSystem<T>();

    // -- update components
    virtual void UpdateComponents(float dt) = 0;
    // -- populates the components of this systems
    virtual void PopulateFromCurrentLevel() = 0;
    // -- clears the components of this system
    virtual void ClearFromCurrentLevel() = 0;

protected:
    // -- actual list of components
    std::vector<T*> components;
};
```

I then also have a `SpriteComponentSystem`, which derives from `ComponentSystem`, but with the `SpriteComponent` as the template type:

```
class SpriteComponentSystem : public ComponentSystem<SpriteComponent>
{
public:
    SpriteComponentSystem();
    ~SpriteComponentSystem();
    virtual void UpdateComponents(float dt);
    virtual void PopulateFromCurrentLevel();
    virtual void ClearFromCurrentLevel();
};
```

Finally, in my `Game` class I am storing a vector of the base class, like so:

```
std::vector<ComponentSystem<Component*>*> systems;
```

However, when I try to push a `SpriteComponentSystem*` into `systems`, I get the following error:

```
C2664 - 'void std::vector<HSZGame::ComponentSystem<HSZGame::Component *> 
*,std::allocator<_Ty> >::push_back(_Ty &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 
'HSZGame::SpriteComponentSystem *' to 
'HSZGame::ComponentSystem<HSZGame::Component *> *const &'
```

I have tried implementing a specific cast from one object to the other, and also tried doing a `dynamic_cast` which worked for compile time but the object was then `nullptr`at runtime.

In case anyone is wondering, `SpriteComponent` does indeed inherit from `Component`, which is the base class. Thanks again for your help everyone!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.    It makes it harder to help you and it limits the ability of other people to find your question if they have the same question in the future.  Put the actual text of the error message in your question.

Comment: `componentsystem<component*>` and `componentsystem<component>` are VERY different types.  Also your code doesn't show componentsystem being a template.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You should start with giving good names to types. Component, ComponentSystem and SpriteComponentSystem are very bad I believe. For me as a reader of your code I can't get any idea what that should be. Is there any relationship, anyone derived or base? Next is: I can't see which error you get in which code part. So please post an error message!

Comment: @xaxzon okay sorry I didn't know that was a rule. And yes, I am well aware that a pointer to a component is different than just a component. How doesn't it show that? It says template<class T> and Invokes T in the vector. It might not be a container but it still uses the template type.

Comment: @Klaus can you elaborate on why the names aren't good? I'm curious to see what you mean. True, but  I do explain the relationship in the question! The post was edited to include an error message as well. Thank you!

Comment: All parts of a software are components. So what is the sense of naming something a component? What is system mean? It is like manager, entity, ... All that gives me no idea what the class should represent. What the class is really *doing*. What is it responsible for? What is the explicitly *not* part of the class. Only "Sprite" gives me an idea of your software. All other things are really without any content.

Comment: Ahh okay I see what you mean - well in Video Game programming specifically, a component is something you can attach to an actor (or entity). I think it is mostly assumed that is what a component is for video game programming, as Unity named their base component class simply just a `Component` as well.

I will take that into consideration though! I'll make sure to document everything well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are initializing a `std::vector<ComponentSystem<Component*>*>` that takes a `ComponentSystem` with a `Component*` template parameter. This means that your vector `components` that is contained within `ComponentSystem` is holding a pointer to a pointer to a `Component`. This might be an error on your part unless you actually mean to hold a pointer to a pointer. If you don't your vector should be initialized `std::vector<ComponentSystem<Component>*>`.

Secondly it seems you would like to use runtime polymorphism so that your vector `systems` can hold not only `ComponentSystem<Component>` objects but also `SpriteComponentSystem` (AKA `ComponentSystem<SpriteComponent>` objects).

Unfortunately the language does not allow this since templates are instantiated at compile time and each instantiation is its own type. The language views `ComponentSystem<Component>` and `ComponentSystem<SpriteComponent>` as separate types and hence the compiler is complaining.

I think you would need to rethink this design philosophy.

Comment: Oooh you are definitely right, I didn't catch that! I definitely do not want the double pointer there, that is a mistake! Thanks for catching that.
But wait - C++ seriously doesn't allow that to take place? I don't understand why that could be...shouldn't a dynamic_cast at least work? Because I specifically am inheriting from `ComponentSystem` and `SpriteComponent` is also inherited from `Component`. Is there really no way to work around this?

Comment: No as far as I know there is not. The C++ compiler does not look for inheritance in the template arguments. It views them as separate types and so the dynamic cast fails. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14292532/5295448

Comment: Ahh I see...yes, looking at that answer it appears to be the case. Thank you, unless someone else comes by with a workaround I will accept your answer for the time being. Thanks!